# Excel not Opened in IIS 6.0

Tags: asp.net, iis

I'm using windows server 2003,iis 6.0. I have a program that creates an excel and open it. through code it is working, while running the same application in IIS 6.0 it is showing an error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". Please help me

Comment: When you say that you ran the code,was this on the same server or was it run on the remote server?

Comment: The problem occurred in Remote server,which is having MS office 2010.

Comment: Yes but when it worked, was that on the remote server?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)